# Sample jQuery sortable not working with MVC4 Web Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm currently working with an MVC project, trying to add drag/drop functionality. Using [this](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) as a reference, I've essentially copied and pasted everything into my project in an attempt to see if it works.

I've added the following thus far into the project's header tag in the _layout.cshtml page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<style>
    #sortable {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 450px;
    }

        #sortable li {
            margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
            padding: 1px;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 90px;
            font-size: 4em;
            text-align: center;
        }
</style>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

and this to an Index.cshtml page

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
```

I figure that, if I can get this sample to work, then parsing data from my controller and getting it to work will not require much more besides parsing data. However, everything I run this project, I get the following error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function," which you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeZzj.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your JavaScript libraries are loaded properly. They have to be in following order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/vcbdheor)**

Comment: In the html source code once i run the page, it loads the the scripts just fine. I went ahead and copied your source code directly into my code and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: I found the problem. MVC loads the jQuery bundle lower down in the body of the _Layout.cshtml page instead of the header section. Thus, it was loading jQuery twice and that's what was messing up the loading of the libraries.